# Is there a page event that runs after a webcontrol render event?

Tags: events, rendering

I have already tried PreRenderComplete and unload is too late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);

.... place code here

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the only event after 'Render' for a control is 'Unload'